# Machine Translation (possible approaches)

Tags: artificial-intelligence, translation

Recently, I’ve been thinking a lot about what to code. I thought about projects that enhance my skill in programming and general problem solving. Also, I wanted something that has an actual purpose. Honestly, I’m interested in building a translator. But not one for programming but one for human languages. 
For example, if I take the German sentence “Ich glaube, du bist verrückt.”, I want to translate it to English. Like “I think you are crazy.”. Now, my question is how is it possible to perform this. I read things like “Translating word by word and then changing word positions, applying punctuation rules” and so on. That would be the “easiest” way to do it. Google translate for example, works with documents: analyzes the source text and tries to find the right translation in a document in our target language.

Don’t hate me for my question because it maybe doesn’t really belong to this community. But I want to code such a thing that is able to translate sentences, not only words. (For now, I only want to translate German to English and vice versa.)

Here is my approach:
Source sentence: (German)
       “Ich arbeite als Koch, aber habe keine Lust mehr.”
Word-by-word translation: (English)
       “I work as chef but have no lust more.”
Since this sentence not correct in terms of grammar, I need to modify it a bit.
Like putting an “a” between “as” and “chef”...

But how can we actually know what to put where and so on?

I know this question isn’t really about “plain” programming. It’s mostly about problem solving.

I hope you guys understand it. I wish you a nice weekend. :)

Comment: I want to get some inspiration and ideas on how to do it.

Comment: You'll need to read *several* books. [NLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) is an entire domain, and uses [machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_machine_learning) techniques

Comment: Start first by reading http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/ then read more specialized NLP books

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/artificial_intelligence/artificial_intelligence_natural_language_processing.htm